# Is there a way to omit or hide an output claim from an inherited policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Currently, I have Two RP Policies that inherit from the TrustFrameworkExtensions policy and use the same UserJourney.

The problem I am running into is that on one policy I need certain output claims to not be included and on another to be included.

The Azure Ad B2C documentation only specifies that we have the ability to overwrite inherited items but it doesn't specify how to omit if that is possible.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="GatherBasicInformation">
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Consent" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_AccountType" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="DisplayValidateMessage" DefaultValue="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="WriteBasicInformation"/>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="EmailVerification-SendLink"/>
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="StepLayout"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

The two output claims that I need to be removed from one RP is extension_consent and extension_accountType.

I have tried removing them from the base technical profile and adding them to the RP policy directly as an overwrite but it moves the claims to the top of the list and not the bottom where I need them.

Is there a way to omit or hide certain output claims?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t omit outputs or remove anything by override. The override is always a merge operation.

Use the `IncludeTechnicalProfile` concept. Youll need 2 seperate user journeys, and the respective technical profile reference in each journey. Then tie the respective user journey id to the 2 RP files.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="GatherBasicInformationMinimum">
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="DisplayValidateMessage" DefaultValue="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="StepLayout"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="GatherBasicInformationAnd2Claims">
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Consent" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_AccountType" Required="true"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="WriteBasicInformation"/>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="EmailVerification-SendLink"/>
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="GatherBasicInformationMinimum"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are referring to. With the RP policy, I am able to add output claims back to the application. In my scenario, I am attempting to prevent users from having to fill out two claims in 1 Rp.

Comment: O, understood, you can do this: First create the minimum version of the Technical profile. Then you create another technical profile, with a new Id, and the 2 output claims only. Add the item 'IncludeInTechnnicalProfile', and include a reference tot he first Tech profile. Then duplicate your user journey, and give the new one a new Id. In the Journey where you want the 2 claims, reference the 2nd tech profile which has the "includes" reference. Each RP will use the respective user journey Id, for whether they want the 2 claims, or not.

Comment: You can see how we use the include function here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L540

Comment: Thanks Jas. I actually just ended up doing this. Can you please make this an answer and I will mark it as the answer? Thanks.